# Disable general speech commands in Hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am making an application with Unity and MRTK for Hololens 2.

I would like to know if it is possible to disable general speech commands.

That is, I want to keep my own voice commands that I have created but I don't want phrases like "Take a picture", "Take a video".... to be recognized.

I've searched the internet but haven't found anything about it.

Does anyone know if there is an option to do this?

Comment: Go to the HoloLens own settings and I think under the language settings you can somewhere turn them off completely for that device .. besides that I think it is as possible as disabling the HoloLens native main menu gesture ... Not ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speech commands in the Unity UWP app are powered by the [same engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/speech-interactions) that supports speech in Windows 10 System. It means if you disable the Speech feature in Settings > Privacy > Speech, the speech recognition will no longer be available in your Unity app. Apart from this, HoloLens does not provide any way to allow you to modify system commands for now. Therefore, it is recommended you avoid using system commands in your app, or consider using the Unity plug-in for the [Cognitive Speech Services SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/setup-platform?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=unity%2Clinux%2Cjre%2Cbrowser) or other third-party speech engines.

Answer (score 0):

You can go setting page,then go to camera ,then find "choose which apps can acess your camera" ,then uncheck Mixed Reality Camera.